# How to get the InputStream of a file that has an absolute path and add it to a StreamedContent object in order to use it in a p:fileDownload?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, download

I have a `pdf` in `C:/Reports/report.pdf` and I need to download it using primefaces. As I have read I need to first get the InputStream of the file and use `DefaultStreamedContent` to get the `StreamedContent` but everything I tried failed.

Help me please it is supposed to be easy and have had lots of problems with this.

The info [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml) uses the /resources/ web directory. I need to do that with the absolute path of the file.

Comment: "Failed" how? Stacktraces? Error messages?

Comment: @kolossus java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolve it doing this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" actionListener="#{downloadBean.prepareDownload()}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadBean.download}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

And:

```
@ManagedBean
public class DownloadBean {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of DownloadBean
 */

private DefaultStreamedContent download;

public void setDownload(DefaultStreamedContent download) {
    this.download = download;
}

public DefaultStreamedContent getDownload() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The file: " + download.getName());
    return download;
}

public void prepareDownload() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C://ImagenesAlmacen/Reporte/report.pdf");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));
}

}
```