# Java - The name of the file is always 'null' when downloading it from server to my location

Tags: java, file, browser, download

I have the following method to download files from a certain folder in my server.

```
public DefaultStreamedContent downloadFiles(String s) {
    try {
        File file = new File(s);
        
        InputStream is = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(file), Files.probeContentType(file.toPath())).getStream();
        byte[] array = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(array));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code works well, as the files in the folder are downloaded correctly (I checked it´s contents). The problem is: The file name, when downloaded by the browser and saved in my `Downloads` folder locally, is always `null`. The files should have the same name of those files stored in the server. Let´s assume that the original file to be downloaded is `server\folder1\folder2\file.extension`. Why, when downloading it, the file name goes as `null` to my `Downloads` folder?

[image]

I thought that the `file path` is assumed as the file´s name, and therefore the Browser/OS saves it as `null` because slashes `\` are not valid for file´s names.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25159580/11703579) answer.
I basically copied the code and adapted to my needs. So, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this? Not sure if the `Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()` is required.

```
    public DefaultStreamedContent downloadFiles(String s) {
    try {
        File file = new File(s);
        String filename = file.getName();
        
        InputStream is = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(file), Files.probeContentType(file.toPath())).getStream();
        byte[] array = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(array), filename);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but the file name is still `null`. The `Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()` is because there are a lot of different `content-types`, so I get them dinamically. I also tried to create a new File without any `path` by copying the original file onto another, but still the same problem.